# Como puedo mandar emails a mi gmail automaticamente usando PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buenas,

Tengo algunas dudas en como programar en php un programa que mande emails a mi gmail automáticamente. En mi caso, quiero que al final del mes automáticamente 
mande un email a mi gmail con algunos datos. Como puedo hacerlo?

Cualquier idea e valida para mi.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Saludos,

Comment: mira aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/66343/32600

Comment: los php se corren cuando son llamados, con php puro seria dificil agendar la tarea para final de mes, lo mas sencillo que podrías hacer es usar una herramienta externa de agendado para llamar a tu php, por ejemplo Crontab

Answer (score 1):

Estimad@, te recomiendo que realizes tu código y luego lo puedas ejecutar mensulmente con CRON JOB, [CRON JOB](https://www.google.co.ve/search?q=jon%20cr%20phpo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=b10GWZGZGY3FZI_9sJgB#q=cron%20job%20php&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbs=lr:lang_1es&lr=lang_es)