# PHPMailer, enviar archivo html con imagen y css externo como mensaje

Tags: php, html, css, phpmailer, imagen

estoy usando el siguiente código para enviar un correo HTML con Archivo adjunto (zip) y si funciona.

Lo que deseo es hacer cambios para:
1. Enviar una plantilla HTML ya pre elaborada que contiene CSS (está en un archivo externo).
2. Incrustar (no adjuntar) una imagen cualquiera en el mensaje.
3. Enviar a varios destinatarios a la vez.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true)
    );
    $mail->Username = "micuenta@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "mipassword";
    $mail->setFrom('no-reply@midominio.com', 'No responder');
    $mail->Subject = 'Probando mensaje';
    $mail->Body = "<h1>Mensaje HTML</h1><br><br>desde PHPMailer<br>";
    $mail->AltBody = 'No se para que sirve';
    $mail->addAttachment('adjuntar/paquete.zip');
    $mail->addAddress('otracuenta@gmail.com', 'Nombre Destinatario');
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Error al enviar: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "¡Mensaje enviado!";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Aquí el código para enviar un correo electrónico con PHPMailer, este permite:
1. Envío desde Localhost
2. Mensaje HTML con CSS e Imágenes incrustadas
3. Soporta Tildes y Eñes (UTF-8)
4. Archivo Adjunto
5. Múltiples destinatarios

**Estructura de carpetas**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- www, contiene index.php y enviacor.php.
- PHPMailer, librería PHP mailer, descárgala de este [enlace](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
- Plantilla, contiene mensaje1.html y estilo.css.
- subidas, carpeta de uploads temporales.

**index.php: contiene el formulario para el mensaje**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Enviar correo HTML+CSS+Imagen+Adjunto desde Localhost</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="enviacor.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Destinatarios</label><br>
        <input type="text" style="width: 500px;" name="txtDestin" value="correo1@outlook.com, correo2@gmail.com"><br>
        <label>Asunto</label><br>
        <input type="text" style="width: 500px;" name="txtAsunto" value = "Probando mensaje HTML"><br>
        <label>Mensaje HTML</label><br>
        <textarea name="txtMensa" style="width: 500px; height: 150px;"></textarea><br>
        <label>Imagen en el mensaje</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="txtImagen" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"><br>
        <label>Archivo adjunto</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="txtAdjun" accept=".zip"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**enviacor.php: envía el correo con los datos del formulario**

```
<?php
    function SubirArchivo ($sfArchivo){
        $dir_subida = 'subidas/';
        $fichero_subido = $dir_subida . basename($_FILES[$sfArchivo]['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$sfArchivo]['tmp_name'], $fichero_subido)) {
            return $fichero_subido;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    /*RECOGER VALORES ENVIADOS DESDE INDEX.PHP*/
    $sDestino = $_POST['txtDestin'];
    $sAsunto = $_POST['txtAsunto'];
    $sMensaje = $_POST['txtMensa'];
    $sImagen = SubirArchivo('txtImagen');
    $sAdjunto = SubirArchivo('txtAdjun');

    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    /*CONFIGURACIÓN DE CLASE*/
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP(); //Indicar que se usará SMTP
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';//permitir envío de caracteres especiales (tildes y ñ)
    /*CONFIGURACIÓN DE DEBUG (DEPURACIÓN)*/
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //Mensajes de debug; 0 = no mostrar (en producción), 1 = de cliente, 2 = de cliente y servidor
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html'; //Mostrar mensajes (resultados) de depuración(debug) en html
    /*CONFIGURACIÓN DE PROVEEDOR DE CORREO QUE USARÁ EL EMISOR(GMAIL)*/
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; //Nombre de host
        // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); // Si su red no soporta SMTP sobre IPv6
        $mail->Port = 587; //Puerto SMTP, 587 para autenticado TLS
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //Sistema de encriptación - ssl (obsoleto) o tls
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;//Usar autenticación SMTP
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true)
        );//opciones para "saltarse" comprobación de certificados (hace posible del envío desde localhost)
    //CONFIGURACIÓN DEL EMISOR
        $mail->Username = "micorreo@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "mipassword";
        $mail->setFrom('no-reply@midominio.com', 'Jorny');

    //CONFIGURACIÓN DEL MENSAJE, EL CUERPO DEL MENSAJE SERA UNA PLANTILLA HTML QUE INCLUYE IMAGEN Y CSS
        $mail->Subject = $sAsunto; //asunto del mensaje
        //incrustar imagen para cuerpo de mensaje(no confundir con Adjuntar)
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($sImagen, 'imagen'); //ruta de archivo de imagen
        //cargar archivo css para cuerpo de mensaje
            $rcss = "plantilla/estilo.css";//ruta de archivo css
            $fcss = fopen ($rcss, "r");//abrir archivo css
            $scss = fread ($fcss, filesize ($rcss));//leer contenido de css
            fclose ($fcss);//cerrar archivo css
        //Cargar archivo html   
            $shtml = file_get_contents('plantilla/mensaje1.html');
        //reemplazar sección de plantilla html con el css cargado y mensaje creado
            $incss  = str_replace('<style id="estilo"></style>',"<style>$scss</style>",$shtml);
            $cuerpo = str_replace('<p id="mensaje"></p>',$sMensaje,$incss);
        $mail->Body = $cuerpo; //cuerpo del mensaje
        $mail->AltBody = '---';//Mensaje de sólo texto si el receptor no acepta HTML

    //CONFIGURACIÓN DE ARCHIVOS ADJUNTOS 
        $mail->addAttachment($sAdjunto);

    //CONFIGURACIÓN DE RECEPTORES
        $aDestino = explode(",",$sDestino);
        foreach ( $aDestino as $i => $sDest){
            $mail->addAddress(trim($sDest), "Destinatario ".$i+1);
        }
    //ENVIAR MENSAJE
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Error al enviar: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Mensaje enviado correctamente";
        //eliminar archivos temporales de carpeta subidas
        unlink($sImagen);
        unlink($sAdjunto);
    }
?>
```

**mensaje1.html: plantilla de mensaje**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Mensaje HTML </title>
    <style id="estilo"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <H1>Este es un mensaje HTML+CSS+IMAGEN+ADJUNTO</H1><br>
    <p id="mensaje"></p><br>
    <img src="cid:imagen" height="100px" width="100px">
</body>
</html>
```

**estilo.css**

```
h1 {
    color:#ff0000;
}
p {
    color:#0000ff;
}
```

**PRUEBA DE ENVÍO**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EN BANDEJA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EL MENSAJE**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya se que es viejo lo posteado, pero te hago una pregunta, si mando mas cosas por el form como el nombre y el area donde trabaja, como puedo hacer para meter eso en el body ademas de la descripcion que sumas aca:                                                                                          
       $cuerpo = str_replace('<p id="mensaje"></p>',$sMensaje,$incss);

Answer (score 1):

Hola buen dia lo que he hecho es que en el mismo archivo de enviar pongo el codigo de la plantilla almacenandola en una variable de esta manera:

```html
$content = '<html>';
$content .= '<head>' ;
$content .= '<style>';
$content .= '.h1{ padding-top:40px; padding-left:250px; padding-bottom:10px;}';
$content .= '.h2{ font-style: italic;  font-size:25px; padding-left: 360px; padding-top:0px;  position:absolute; whith:10px; }';
$content .= '.tel{padding-left:250px; padding-top:60px;}';
$content .= 'h1 { color:green; font-style: italic; font-size:30px ;}';
$content .= 'td {  border: black 1px solid}';
$content .= '.tdr { text-align:left; }';

$content .= '.td { text-align:center; padding-left:100px; padding-right:100px;  padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; border-color: black; }';
$content .= '.td1 { background-color:white; border-color:white; padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px; }';
$content .= '.td2 { border-color: white; padding:15px; padding-top:5px; }';
$content .= '.td3 { background-color:white; border-color:white; padding-left:60px;padding-right:60px; }';
$content .= '.td4 { padding-left:60px;padding-right:60px; border-color: white; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;}';
$content .= '.table1 { text-align:center; border:0px solid black; padding:1px; position:relative; top:80px;left:10px;}';
$content .= '.table2 { border:1px solid black; padding:1px; position:relative; top:80px;left:10px;border-collapse: collapse;}';
$content .= '.table3 { text-align:center; border:0px solid black; padding:1px; position:relative; top:100px;left:10px;}';



$content .= '</style>';
$content .= '</head><body>';


$content .= '<table class="table1"> <tr>';puedes concatenar asi las variables como la de asunto
$content .= '<td class="td1">Asunto: '.$asunto.'</td></tr>';
```

Toda esta variable la mandas con la funcion
$mail->MsgHTML($content);  <-----espero te sirva

Comment: La idea es tener la plantilla fuera (archivo html) así se reduce las líneas de código.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

PHPMailer - GMail SMTP test

// Creamos una nueva instancia
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Activamos el servicio SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
// Activamos / Desactivamos el "debug" de SMTP 
// 0 = Apagado 
// 1 = Mensaje de Cliente 
// 2 = Mensaje de Cliente y Servidor 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

// Log del debug SMTP en formato HTML 
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

// Servidor SMTP (para este ejemplo utilizamos gmail) 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

// Puerto SMTP 
$mail->Port = 587;

// Tipo de encriptacion SSL ya no se utiliza se recomienda TSL 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

// Si necesitamos autentificarnos 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

// Usuario del correo desde el cual queremos enviar, para Gmail recordar usar el usuario completo (usuario@gmail.com) 
$mail->Username = "codejobs@gmail.com";

// Contraseña 
$mail->Password = "aprendeaprogramar";

// Conectamos a la base de datos 
$db = new mysqli('hostname', 'usuario', 'cotraseña', 'basededatos');

if ($db->connect_errno > 0) { 
    die('Imposible conectar [' . $db->connect_error . ']'); 
}

// Creamos la sentencias SQL 
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM personas");

// Iniciamos el "bucle" para enviar multiples correos.

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    //Añadimos la direccion de quien envia el corre, en este caso Codejobs, primero el correo, luego el nombre de quien lo envia.

```
$mail->setFrom('codejobs@gmail.com', 'CodeJobs!'); 
$mail->addAddress($row['PersonasEmail'], $row['PersonasNombre']); 

//La linea de asunto 
$mail->Subject = 'Bienvenido a Codejobs!'; 

// La mejor forma de enviar un correo, es creando un HTML e insertandolo de la siguiente forma, PHPMailer permite insertar, imagenes, css, etc. (No se recomienda el uso de Javascript) 

$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contenido.html'), dirname(__FILE__)); 

// Enviamos el Mensaje 
$mail->send(); 

// Borramos el destinatario, de esta forma nuestros clientes no ven los correos de las otras personas y parece que fuera un único correo para ellos. 
$mail->ClearAddresses();
```

}
?>

Estimad@, revisa este link, [Envio de emails masivos o simples con PHP, MySQLi y PHPMailer](https://www.codejobs.biz/es/blog/2014/07/17/envio-de-emails-masivos-o-simples-con-php-mysqli-y-phpmailer)